# Using shell code for LocalForward in ssh config file

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, ssh-config

I have this configuration in my ssh config file,

```
Host *+*
ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | sed -e 's/+[^+]*$//;s/\([^+=]*\)=\([^+]*\)$/\2 -l \1/; s/^\([^+:]*\):\([0-9]*\)+/-p \2 \1+/') -W $(echo %h | sed -e 's/^.*+//; s/:.*$//;'):$(echo %h | sed -e 's/^.*+//; /:/!s/^.*/22/; s/^.*://' ;)
```

which allows me to do some basic host jumps, like:

```
ssh host1+host2 # will ssh into host2 via host1
```

Is there a why to do the same trick for the `LocalForward` command (`-L`) ?
I tried something like this, but it didn't work,

```
Host host1+*
    user root
    Hostname %h
    ProxyCommand ssh host1 -W %h:%p
    LocalForward 0.0.0.0:8080 $(echo %h | awk -F'+' '{print $2}'):80
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The [SSH configuration file](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5) does not take or evaluate shell code.

The reason your first thing works is that it's executed by the shell as part of the invocation of the proxy command.

But I suppose `LocalCommand` may be used in a similar way as your proxy command to invoke `ssh -f -L...`.  I've never done this or seen it done though. See also `PermitLocalCommand`.

Comment: I appreciate a downvote along with a comment. (or possibly the other way around)